# Is Pose View in rqt buggy or not finished?

Tags: ros, opengl, ros-groovy, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rqt when I run a rviz and the add a "Pose View" the Pose View seems not to work properly and when I kill it the rviz does not work anymore so that I have to restart rqt.

Is this well known? It seems to me that a lot of the plugins malfunctions so maybe it is just a matter of time before they are finished. Or is this unknown so I should try to report every bug I find?

Edit:

Versions:

```
tompe@heyer:~$ dpkg -p ros-groovy-rqt-rviz
Package: ros-groovy-rqt-rviz
Priority: extra
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 112
Maintainer: Dorian Scholz <scholz@sim.tu-darmstadt.de>
Architecture: i386
Version: 0.2.8-0precise-20130205-1933-+0000

tompe@heyer:~$ dpkg -p ros-groovy-rviz
Package: ros-groovy-rviz
Priority: extra
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 7245
Maintainer: David Gossow <dgossow@willowgarage.com>
Architecture: i386
Version: 1.9.20-0precise-20130205-1910-+0000


tompe@heyer:~$ dpkg -p ros-groovy-rqt-pose-view
Package: ros-groovy-rqt-pose-view
Priority: extra
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 125
Maintainer: Dorian Scholz <scholz@sim.tu-darmstadt.de>
Architecture: i386
Version: 0.2.8-0precise-20130125-2316-+0000
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55480/is-pose-view-in-rqt-buggy-or-not-finished?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-02-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-02-18**:
Although I don't see exactly the same behaviour, I see combining `rqt_rviz` & `rqt_pose_view` seems faulty. I opened a ticket http://goo.gl/LUCDY

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-02-18**:
Meanwhile can you tell us the version you're using by like `dpkg -p ros-groovy-rqt-rviz, dpkg -p ros-groovy-rviz, dpkg -p ros-groovy-rqt-pose-view`?

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-02-18**:
Added the version information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Easiest workaround came up after the [discussion among the original developers](http://goo.gl/LUCDY); run `rqt_gui` in `multi process` mode by:

```
$ rqt_gui -m
```

## This will work around any other issues that arise from running `OpenGL` in a single process.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0